# И снова о "блине"

Tags: этикет, обсценная-лексика

Прочитал вопрос о том, является ли слово "блин" заменой мата. Ответили, что оно может быть просто связкой слов для выражения эмоциональной окраски.
Но у меня тогда вопрос: является ли в таком случае (в данном контексте) слово "блин" ругательством, и более того, непристойным ругательством, или это просто слово-паразит?

Comment: А я в шутку, вместо страшных ругательств, говорю "блинский блин!!".

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю, что это слово паразит. Я знаю многих людей, которые никогда не ругаются матом,  но слово "блин" как междометие используют очень часто. Если человек не ругается матом, если, когда он слышит слово "блин" у него не возникает ассоциации с нецензурным словом, какая же это замена. Хотя могут быть и такие люди, которые используют это слово как замену: в приятельской компании, например, ругнулись, а другой обстановке сказали "блин". но, по-моему, легче промолчать, чем таким образом заменять. Так что зависит от ситуации, интонации, вложенного смысла: по речи видно, ругается человек, или это у него слово паразит.